# Process.StandardInput.WriteLine for CMD wont write as its supposed to

Tags: c#, cmd, command-line

so i made a Process class and named it cmd and it is supposed to automatically run a command but when i test it it comes out different then the command itself so i tried multiple things like put a @ behind the string and even tried removing all of the backslashes behind the quotes and added a + in the middle everytime i had to remove one of those backslashes.

> This is my code i use to execute the command

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Command");
            try
            {
                Process cmd = new Process();
                cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                cmd.Start();

                cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("REG EXPORT \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Active Setup\\Installed Components\\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}\" \r\n\"%TEMP%.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.SOFTWARE.Microsoft.Active Setup.Installed Components.A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073.reg\" \r\nREG EXPORT \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Active Setup\\Installed Components\\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}\" \r\n\"%TEMP%.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.SOFTWARE.Microsoft.Active Setup.Installed Components.A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073.reg\"\r\n\r\nREG ADD \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Active Setup\\Installed Components\\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}\" /v \"IsInstalled\" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f \r\nREG ADD \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Active Setup\\Installed Components\\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}\" /v \"IsInstalled\" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f\r\n\r\nRundll32 iesetup.dll, IEHardenLMSettings \r\nRundll32 iesetup.dll, IEHardenUser \r\nRundll32 iesetup.dll, IEHardenAdmin\r\n\r\nREG DELETE \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Active Setup\\Installed Components\\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}\" /f /va REG DELETE \"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Active Setup\\Installed Components\\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}\" /f /va");
                cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
                cmd.StandardInput.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

> it works fine with other commands but when i try this one it just wont work

> this is the code in its original state that i want to execute

```
REG EXPORT "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}" 
"%TEMP%.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.SOFTWARE.Microsoft.Active Setup.Installed Components.A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073.reg" 
REG EXPORT "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}" 
"%TEMP%.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.SOFTWARE.Microsoft.Active Setup.Installed Components.A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073.reg"

REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}" /v "IsInstalled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f 
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}" /v "IsInstalled" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Rundll32 iesetup.dll, IEHardenLMSettings 
Rundll32 iesetup.dll, IEHardenUser 
Rundll32 iesetup.dll, IEHardenAdmin

REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A7-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}" /f /va REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\{A509B1A8-37EF-4b3f-8CFC-4F3A74704073}" /f /va
```

as you can see in the original command there are no extra backslashes or any sort of \r\n
i think because of this it wont work but when i remove all of those things the command itself wont work anymore.

anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: You are aware that you could perform these actions programmatically from your own program rather than "hiring" cmd as a middle-man and forcing yourself to funnel everything to it as commands, aren't you?

Comment: what do you mean by forcing myself by funneling everything?

Comment: The %TEMP% isn't getting substituted.